# Get weekly report from given month

Tags: php

I have here a code that gets all the dates. What I want to achieve is to get the weekly report base on the month. I've search so many websites and forum but cant find anything. Any help that is related to the question is very much appreciated.

```
$startOfWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Monday this week"));
$currentDayOfMonth=date('Y-m-01');
$maxDays=date('t');
  for ($i=0; $i<$maxDays;$i++){
    echo date("l, d M", strtotime($currentDayOfMonth . " + $i day"))."<br />";
  }
```

And this is the result of the above code

```
Monday, 01 Apr
Tuesday, 02 Apr
Wednesday, 03 Apr
Thursday, 04 Apr
Friday, 05 Apr
Saturday, 06 Apr
Sunday, 07 Apr
Monday, 08 Apr
Tuesday, 09 Apr
Wednesday, 10 Apr
Thursday, 11 Apr
Friday, 12 Apr
Saturday, 13 Apr
Sunday, 14 Apr
Monday, 15 Apr
Tuesday, 16 Apr
Wednesday, 17 Apr
Thursday, 18 Apr
Friday, 19 Apr
Saturday, 20 Apr
Sunday, 21 Apr
Monday, 22 Apr
Tuesday, 23 Apr
Wednesday, 24 Apr
Thursday, 25 Apr
Friday, 26 Apr
Saturday, 27 Apr
Sunday, 28 Apr
Monday, 29 Apr
Tuesday, 30 Apr
```

What I want to achieve is something like this

```
WEEK 1
Monday, 01 Apr
Tuesday, 02 Apr
Wednesday, 03 Apr
Thursday, 04 Apr
Friday, 05 Apr
Saturday, 06 Apr
Sunday, 07 Apr

WEEK 2
Monday, 08 Apr
Tuesday, 09 Apr
Wednesday, 10 Apr
Thursday, 11 Apr
Friday, 12 Apr
Saturday, 13 Apr
Sunday, 14 Apr

WEEK 3
Monday, 15 Apr
Tuesday, 16 Apr
Wednesday, 17 Apr
Thursday, 18 Apr
Friday, 19 Apr
Saturday, 20 Apr
Sunday, 21 Apr

WEEK 4
Monday, 22 Apr
Tuesday, 23 Apr
Wednesday, 24 Apr
Thursday, 25 Apr
Friday, 26 Apr
Saturday, 27 Apr
Sunday, 28 Apr

WEEK 5
Monday, 29 Apr
Tuesday, 30 Apr
```

Do you know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```
$startOfWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Monday this week"));
$currentDayOfMonth=date('Y-m-01');
$maxDays=date('t');
  for ($i=0, $week = 1; $i<$maxDays;$i++){
    if ($i%7==0) {
        if ($week > 1) echo "<br/>";
        echo "WEEK " . $week++ . "<br/>";
    }
    echo date("l, d M", strtotime($currentDayOfMonth . " + $i day"))."<br />";
  }
```

Comment: By the way, what if I want to get the weekly report between two months. like january to february.

Comment: Alright, for that, gimme a little more clarification. Do you want a week to start the 1st  day of each month?

Comment: Yes. And ends with last day of the month.

Comment: Then just take the whole code in a function and accept a particular month as a parameter. You can now call this function to print the weekly report of any month. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the days are divisible by 7 & print your week:

```
$startOfWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Monday this week"));
$currentDayOfMonth=date('Y-m-01');
$maxDays=date('t');

$weekNo = 1;
echo "WEEK 1";

for ($i=0; $i<$maxDays;$i++){
    if (($i + 1)%7 == 0) {
        $weekNo++;

        echo "<br />WEEK ".$weekNo;
    }

    echo date("l, d M", strtotime($currentDayOfMonth . " + $i day"))."<br />";
}
```